# If/Then statements no longer function

Tags: python, if-statement

I have no idea how this happened, but I wrote a few if/then programs earlier today and they've suddenly stopped working the way they're supposed to, in only a few hours time.

I tried sniffing out every syntax bug I possibly could, but nothing seems to make the code function.

```
num=(input("Input a number from 1 to 10"))
if int(num) == range(1, 10):
        if int(num)==int(1):
            print("I")
        else:
            if int(num)==int(2):
                print("II")
            else:
                if int(num)==int(3):
                    print("III")
                else:
                    if int(num)==int(4):
                        print("IV")
                    else:
                        if int(num)==int(5):
                            print("V")
                        else:
                            if int(num)==int(6):
                                print("VI")
                            else:
                                if int(num)==int(7):
                                    print("VII")
                                else:
                                    if int(num)==int(8):
                                        print("VIII")
                                    else:
                                        if int(num)==int(9):
                                            print("VIV")
                                        else:
                                            if int(num)==int(10):
                                                print("X")
                                            else:
                                                print("this aint it chief")
else:
        print("ERROR-Please give a number from 1 to 10")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"?

Comment: When I run the program, any input entered, regardless of how valid, will immediately run to the final else statement.

Comment: If it's hitting the final `else` then the problem must be with `if int(num) == range(1, 10)`. Give that another look.

Answer (score 1):

Note this line: `if int(num) == range(1, 10):`

Where expression `int(num) == range(1, 10)` evaluates to `False`. That's because the object `range(1, 10)` is not a *number*. That is a *function* (or, more strictly, *generator*, but that's not important here).

That's not how you check whether is number within some bounds. Use `if int(num) in range(1, 10):` instead.

[Edit]
Forgot to mention: `range(a, b)` generates values from `a` to `b - 1` inclusively. It will not contain value `b`.